# App size with different iPhone models

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have a problem with my app, the app is simple and it was created in a viewcontroller of iphone 5s size.

But problem is here, that when I run app on Iphone 6 mode ore 6 plus or 4s, the size doesn't change in proportion with the iPhone size, I fixed the background problem with dragging the background image to view and clicking "Center Horizontally in Container", "Center Vertically in Container", "Equal Widths", "Equal Heights".

But when I try to do the same with the small round buttons, the app is destroyed and all the button are deformed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're hardcoding all UI positions and sizes in your app. Take a look into [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). As the name suggests, it allows you to have the same UI layout on all the devices you support, without hardcoding any frames.

Comment: Depends on how you coded your app in the first place. Removing the hardcoded number values for position and sizes and replacing it with auto layout should work.

Answer (score 0):

While I personally would not use it, there is different solution ; Use compatibility mode with 5s / 6. What it means is that your device will basically think it is iPhone 5, but it will scale it up on bigger devices to fit the screen.

How you do it is simple, it is driven by launch screen images, if you remove iphone6 and 6 plus launch image, your views will properly upscale and you have to develop your application only for iPhone 5.

It is simple solution as easy short term fix, but as others already suggested, it would be better if you just used AutoLayout.

Hope it helps!

Edit:

Here are some links for future reading:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips
- http://taylorfranklin.me/2014/09/09/what-iphone-6-screen-size-means-for-developers/